# rgenoud - How to pass parameters to the function?

Tags: r

I have a function that currently plays nice with rgenoud.  It has one parameter (xx) and rgenoud will optimize xx perfectly.

However, I would like to add a second parameter to my function that wouldnt be optimized by rgendoud .  For example, I would like my function to either fit a model with a gaussian link or a poisson link and to specify that when I call rgenoud.

Any idea?
thanks

---

edit: here is a minimal working example of what I mean.  How would you get the last line to work?

adstock reflect the fact that TV advertising should have an impact on the number of quotes of future weeks.
Adstock[t] = Ads[t] + rate* Ads[t-1] + rate^2*Ads[t-2] + ....  + rate^max_memory * Ads[t-max_memory]

We want rgenoud to figure out what rate and max_memory will return the model with the best fit. Best fit is defined as the lowest RMSE.

```
set.seed(107)

library(fpp)
library(rgenoud)

adstock_k <- function(x, adstock_rate = 0, max_memory = 12){
 learn_rates <- rep(adstock_rate, max_memory+1) ^ c(0:max_memory)
 adstocked_advertising <- stats::filter(c(rep(0, max_memory), x), learn_rates, method="convolution")
 adstocked_advertising <- adstocked_advertising[!is.na(adstocked_advertising)]
 return(as.numeric(adstocked_advertising))
}

getRMSE <- function(x, y) {
  mean((x-y)^2) %>% sqrt
}

df <- data.frame(insurance) %>% 
    mutate(Quotes = round (Quotes*1000, digits = 0 ))
df$idu <- as.numeric(rownames(df))           

my_f <- function(xx){
  adstock_rate <- xx[1]
  adstock_memory <- xx[2]
  df.temp <- df %>%
    mutate(adstock = adstock_k(TV.advert, adstock_rate/100, adstock_memory ))
  mod <- lm(data=df.temp, Quotes ~ adstock )
  getRMSE( df.temp$Quotes, predict(mod))
}

domaine <- cbind(c(30,1), c(85, 8))
#this works
min_f <- genoud(my_f, nvars = 2, max = F, pop.size=1000, wait.generations=10, Domains = domaine, data.type.int =  T) 

#here I try to add a second parameter to the function.
my_f2 <- function(xx,first_n_weeks=20){
  adstock_rate <- xx[1]
  adstock_memory <- xx[2]
  df.temp <- df %>%
    filter(idu<= first_n_weeks) %>%
    mutate(adstock = adstock_k(TV.advert, adstock_rate/100, adstock_memory ))
  mod <- lm(data=df.temp, Quotes ~ adstock )
  getRMSE( df.temp$Quotes, predict(mod))
}

#this doesnt work
min_f2 <- genoud(my_f2(first_n_week=10), nvars = 2, max = F, pop.size=1000, wait.generations=10, Domains = domaine, data.type.int =  T)
```

Comment: This is quite broad. Please provide a (maybe simplified) version of your function.

Comment: Are you asking how to pass the `first_n_weeks` argument to `my_f2`? If so, you just stick it in the call to `genoud`, e.g. `genoud(my_f2, nvars = 2, max = F, pop.size=1000, wait.generations=10, Domains = domaine, data.type.int =  T, first_n_weeks = 10)`.

Comment: @WeihuangWong Yes, that's exactly what I was trying to do - I had given up - thanks!!  If you add an answer, I'll gladly accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the argument in the call to `genoud`, e.g.

```
genoud(my_f2, nvars = 2, max = F, pop.size=1000, wait.generations=10, Domains = domaine, data.type.int = T, first_n_weeks = 10)
```